# Is there a way to select a specific column in a Snowpark DF if it's in JSON format and I don't want it in full (I want to extract a value)?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I get that once you've created a dataframe, it's very easy to load specific columns. For example:

df_selected = df.select("col1", "col2", "col3")

However, what happens if col3 contains JSON data and I only don't want all of it. This is one such value in the column:

[image]

If I was querying this in SQL (in Snowflake) and just wanted the designer, I could just write it was follows:

SELECT col3:Construction_method:CAD:designer FROM df

I've tried various variations of the following code in Snowpark but none work:

df_selected = df.select("col3:Construction_method:CAD:designer")

Is there any way to achieve this or does this need to be done at the point when the data frame is initially created and thus could be written in SQL like this:

session.sql("SELECT col3:Construction_method:CAD:designer FROM DF")

Ideally, I'd like to do this after the initial DF has been created in Snowpark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a Snowpark expert, but there is a section on dealing with variant data in Snowpark here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/python/working-with-dataframes#label-snowpark-python-dataframe-semistructured-traverse

And this would lead me to assume that this is what you're looking for:

```
df_selected = df.select(col("col3")["Construction_method"]["CAD"]["designer"])
```

Let me know if that works for you.  It saves you from Pandas and should execute as you want it to in Snowpark.